# How to format the string values without space to datetime in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, formatting, data-science

i have a pandas `df`:

|  | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 20221101 |
| 1 | 20220510 |
| 2 | 20230102 |

The dates are string and are formatted as %Y%M%D

I want to format the entire column to %D%M%Y. Like this:

|  | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 01-11-2022 |
| 1 | 10-05-2022 |
| 2 | 02-01-2023 |

I tried the datetime doule and other custom formating.

Comment: Use `date.strptime()` to parse the datees and `date.strftime()` to format them.

Comment: "I tried..." what?  Show your coding attempt.

Comment: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`

Comment: Breaking the string into 3 pieces and calling `int` on each would be dead simple.